# How to mimic the deterministic convergence via taking the expectation?

Tags: convergence

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a lower bounded function that satisfies the following property for a given $\{x_k\}_{k\geq0}$ sequence:

$$
f(x_k) - f(x_{k+1}) \geq c ||x_{k+1}-{x_k}||^2
$$
where $c>0$.
The above means after each step the function value is less or equal than the previous value. Since the function is lower bounded, we can say $\{f(x_k)\}_{k\geq0}$ converges.

I want to mimic the above convergence in a stochastic setting. I would assume that the analogy should like the following (correct me if I am not right):

Suppose we have the following for a given random sequence $\{y_k\}_{k\geq0}$:

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(y_k) - f(y_{k+1})] \geq d \mathbb{E}[||y_{k+1}-{y_k}||^2]
$$
where $d>0$ and expectation is taken with respect to $y_{k+1}$ and $y_k$ is known at $k$-th step.

**Question**:Is it safe to say that the function value sequence $\{\mathbb{E}[f(y_k)]\}_{k\geq0}$ converges? Am I in the right direction to convert my deterministic problem to a stochastic one?

Answer (score 0):

$E[\| y_{k+1} - y_k\|^2] \geq 0$ since $\| y_{k+1} - y_k\|^2 \geq 0$ almost surely. So $Ef(y_k) - Ef(y_{k+1}) \geq 0$. Since $f$ is lower bounded, so is $Ef(y_k)$ uniformly over $k$. Thus, $Ef(y_k)$ is nonincreasing and bounded from below and thus it must converge.

Alternatively, applying the deterministic argument almost surely, we have that $f(y_k)(\omega)$ is nonincreasing and lower bounded for $\omega$ contained in a set with probability $1$. Thus, $f(y_k)$ converges almost surely to some random variable $f_{\infty}$ monotonely where $f_{\infty}$ is lower bounded almost surely. We can then apply the monotone convergence theorem to conclude that
$$E f(y_k) \rightarrow E[f_{\infty}]$$
where $E[f_{\infty}]$ is lower bounded.